# Displaying an image added via file upload using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Need to display an image added to the document via file upload, before sending it to the server.

Have the following markup:

```
<body>
    <div id="image-container">
        <h2>Image Chosen form the File System:</h2>
        <!-- Chosen image is displayed here, in an image tag via Javascript -->
    </div>
    <label for="image-input">Select an Image from Your File System to Display Above</label>
    <input id="image-input" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Display Image Chosen" />
</body>
```

The chosen image should be displayed in the div when the user clicks on the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DO SOMETHING LIKE THIS..

JS code below:

```
function readURL(input) {

if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function (e) {
        $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
}
```

}

```
$("#imgInp").change(function(){
  readURL(this);
});
```

and the associated HTML:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <input type='file' id="imgInp" />
  <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
</form>
```

CHECK THIS FIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/LvsYc/

Comment: If u want to display the image when a button is clicked , then u have to call  that function inside a button using onclick

Answer (score -1):

You have to put a function that calls a javascript script to store the image first on the cache of your server. Then an onclick action will call the function that takes care of rendering your image will get the image from the cache and render it.